# Editing Freeform entry statuses

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is it possible to edit / add to the entry Statuses in Freeform or can I only select from the default Pending, Open and Closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freeform status additions are available to the Pro version in the preferences area.